# Why do horses shake their head "no" even when saddled?

Tags: survivalcraft

I was playing survivalcraft this morning. I was riding my black horse when all of a sudden it stopped. When I attempted to make it move again it shook its head no. The horse was already saddled. What's going on? Is it a glitch? Is the horse tired? What?

Answer (score 2):

They are being stubborn. You have to throw a rose/red flower at them to start moving, and when they are nodding their head then you can get back on and ride again!

Comment: You can also feed them grass and other foods.

Answer (score -1):

That happens to me all the time I just give my horse hay or some kind of food then I hop back on er. Make sure you are also feeding you horse once a day because they stop when they are hungry sometimes. How this comment helped